# How to configure basic authentication over SSL for Solr running on Jetty

Tags: authentication, ssl, solr, jetty

Is there a tutorial to set up basic authentication over SSL for Solr running on jetty?
I am running Solr 5.1. I have followed the following to enable SSL:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL

This works fine. I am able to configure basic authentication without SSL using following:
http://muddyazian.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-require-password-authentication.html

However, when I enable basic authentication over SSL I get following error during start up:

```
r@cb52821: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator@2fed6d94 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@cb52821
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator@2fed6d94 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@cb52821
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
"/opt/solr-5.1.0/server/logs/solr.log" 153L, 13832C                                                                                1,1           Top
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

I would really appreciate if someone can provide pointers to a tutorial or a solution for this.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this one as well.

Comment: Any news guys? I'm checking this for solr 7.5, over http all works, with https not...

Comment: Just a side note, be sure you can figure out this aggravating task before you put any effort into developing an app that you discover you can't secure.